# How to Report an error in the Qiskit Textbook?

Tags: qiskit, textbook-and-exercises

In the Qiskit Textbook in Chapter "Introduction to Quantum Computing -> Entangled states -> The CX gate revisited" the following sentence might be wrong:

> If we do the CX now, we will see an effect. It flips the target qubit to  as well.

I think it should say that the control qubit is the one flipping.

Comment: If you're sure about the error you can still open an issue or even do a PR on the [github repo of the textbook](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qiskit Textbook is fully open-source and maintained in GitHub:

https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook

You can submit [issues](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook/issues) following the [predefine templates](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook/issues/new/choose). If the issue is simple and you think that no discussion is needed, you can submit a PR directly and it will be reviewed by the project maintainers.